# .NET Core 3.1 - Angular 9 - MVC - Dealing with empty values on data creation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an angular 9 .NET Core 3.1 project and as I want to save data, some fields are not populated

so I get the error **The JSON value could not be converted to ...** since the value is an empty string or a null

the idea is that my data models have some **fields that make sens only when data is fetched (Id, CreationDate...)**

but **when I create a record in a form for the first time, these data dont exist yet**

model in typescript:

```
export interface SomeData{
  Id: number, >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> these cannot be populated by the client when creating the record in db (.NET/SQL) will do this
  CreationDate: string, >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  Name: string,
  Country: number,
  Street: string,
  ...
}
```

model in .NET :

```
public class SomeData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public short Country { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }        
}
```

question :

- do I create a different data model for post/insert and get/select flows?
- do I fill these values anyway, even if the backend will override these ?

or am I missing something ?

thanks for the time you'll spend on this question

Comment: Does it solve the problem if you use the nullable data type int? Id and DateTime? CreationDate on your model in C#?

Comment: indeed the conversion does not occur if using nullable !!

Answer (score 1):

apparently, mapping is done by MVC framework if the type is not nullable
so adding a ? does the trick

```
public class SomeData
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public short Country { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While submitting form data from angular, you can generate random no. for id, and current date time for CreationDate.

Comment: this makes no sens, it's not to the client nor the c# code to generate id's